# converting Hibernate into Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, hibernate-annotations, spring-orm, jpa-annotations

we have a existing Hibernate application with Spring , we had hbm.xml files but now we want to create a hybrid application of xml and annotation both , so that in future we can move to spring Data jpa 
here is my configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">

    <!-- Added for property holder configuration -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
        <property name="location">
            <value>WEB-INF/***_hibernate.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dabtDataSource" />
        <property name="mappingJarLocations">
            <list>
                <value>WEB-INF/lib/******.jar</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.database.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">${hibernate.default.schema}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheProvider</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.shared">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I have included spring orm , spring core , spring mvc , hibernate jpa and hibernate core files still i am getting below eror on server strt up

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/***/Config/Lev1/Web/WebAppServer/SASServer8_1/webapps/*******.war/WEB-INF/lib/solutions.jar!/resources/connection-config.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Entity
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1039)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:972)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    ... 90 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Entity
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1032)
    ... 98 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Entity
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.<init>(AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.java:91)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
    ... 100 more
```

Comment: Nice that you have everything but with the JPA api jars it isn't going to work.

Comment: @M.Deinum What shall i do then i want a hybrid application of annotation and xml but even this simple thing is not working , any suggestions need urgent help.

Comment: Have you actually READ the comment... You are missing a dependency, add it.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am sorry but which jar exactly am i missing ? I have spring orm , hibernate core and Hibernate jpa jar, can you please help me out with this ?

Comment: as mentioned, the JPA api jars. You only have implementations.

Comment: as @M.Deinum mentioned, this one: `<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: Well if you want a really old one, then yes... I suggest a 2.0 or 2.1 edition instead...

Comment: @M.Deinum yes will add but isnt the same clsses present in Hibernate jpa ? moreover do we need to add hibernate jpa jar ?

Comment: @Jaiwo99  yes will add but isnt the same clsses present in Hibernate jpa ? moreover do we need to add hibernate jpa jar

Comment: Well apparently they aren't, so not sure which jars you are talking about (I suggest added that to your question). Also you should be using maven to manage those depenencies instead of trying to hunt for your own.

Comment: still it isnt working my dependencies are

Comment: @Amit146 you also need to add <context:annotation-config/> to your applicationContext to scan all annotations

Comment: still it isnt working my dependencies are  
Hibernate;3.2.6.0,  springframework.beans;3.2, javax.persistence;1.0.1

Comment: @cralfaro but it is unable to create the sessionFactory i guess looking after annotations is the secondary thing.

Comment: @M.Deinum still it isnt working any idea ? need urgent help on this.

Comment: If you still have the same error you don't have the jars you think you have. At least not at runtime.

Comment: @M.Deinum do i use javax.persistece API or hibernate annotations API ?

Comment: @Jaiwo99 do i use javax.persistece API or hibernate annotations API ?

Comment: If you have read the stack trace you can answer that yourself.... `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Entity` is quite a giveaway of that answer.

Comment: @M.Deinum sorry but i have on elast doubt why do I need to add Hibernate.annotaions and Hibernate.Commons.annotations jars when i do have javax.persistence which i guess have all the classes.

Comment: @Jaiwo99 sorry but i have on elast doubt why do I need to add Hibernate.annotaions and Hibernate.Commons.annotations jars when i do have javax.persistence which i guess have all the classes.

Comment: Because those serve a different purpose and contain other annotations (and are for annotation processing support in hibernate).